# Difference between "halt" and "shutdown now"?

Tags: shutdown, remote-control

Ubuntu one remote uses `sudo -S -p '' halt` for shutdown and does not work to the end.
leaveing monitor on with message

> will now halt
>
> [22225.11163] halted

What is the difference between `sudo -S -p " halt`  and `sudo shutdown now`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `-S` and `-p` switches for `sudo` have no importance in this case. Here is what they do, respectively.

> The `-S` switch causes `sudo` to read the password from STDIN. This allows, for example, a password to be piped to `sudo` through `echo` or `cat`.
>
> The `-p` switch allows you to override the default password prompt and use a custom one, or none at all.

---

The important difference is in the two commands being issued by `sudo`.

> The `halt` command, if invoked without the `-p` switch, simply halts the OS and stops all CPUs. Once the system is cleanly halted, the user may safely hit the Power button on his computer manually.
>
> The `poweroff`, `shutdown -h now`, and `halt -p` commands all do the same thing as `halt` alone, while additionally sending an ACPI command to signal the power supply unit to disconnect the main power. This prevents you from having to physically push the Power button on your computer.

Comment: `shutdown -h now` does not necessarily turn the power off either. As per `man shutdown`, it depends on the system. `shutdown -H now` (notice the caps on `H`) is the one guaranteed to be equivalent to `halt`

Answer (score 11):

`halt` is not `shutdown`, they are different commands. The former does not turn the power off, unless `-p` option is used

From the manual (`man halt`): *"-p, --poweroff : Instructs the halt command to instead behave as poweroff."*

And, in your case, `-p` was *not* used in the `halt`command, hence your computer was *not* powered off.

Do not confuse this -p with the one from `sudo`, it's a different parameter for a different command. From `man sudo`:

- `-S` *The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device.  The password must be followed by a newline character.*
- `-p prompt` *The -p (prompt) option allows you to override the default password prompt and use a custom one.*

In your case, `prompt` is empty (no message displayed for sudo when asking password), and -S makes sudo accept root password vi stdin (so password may be supplied using pipes and redirection from other commands instead of being typed)

Answer (score 7):

There is a good answer at the [Unix SE site](http://unix.stackexchange.com) about the `shutdown` vs `halt` issue: [What is the difference between Halt and Shutdown commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8694)

As for the `sudo -S -p ''` part, this will remove the message about asking the password in the terminal (You still have enter your password though)

For example running `sudo <some_command>` will give this output before running this command:

> [sudo] password for :

But running `sudo -S -p '' <some_command>` will hide that message.

In fact, the message that you put in the quotes, is replacing the previous message.

Go ahead and try the following, and see the difference:

```
 sudo -S -p 'Hey, I am a custom message.' ls
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no difference between halt command and shutdown in terms of the user intention. The thin difference is that in halt you have to conveniently push the power button to shutdown the system whereas in shutdown command it will automatically instruct the Advanced Configuration Power Interface (ACPI) to sent a signal to the power unit to turn off the system.