# Problem with `sudo halt` command 

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “halt” and “shutdown now”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190202/difference-between-halt-and-shutdown-now)

When you execute a command ( `sudo halt` ) Command System stops working 
So you execute this command on another set of computers and the result was that the freeze system

Comment: look: http://askubuntu.com/a/190214/83046

Answer (score 0):

`sudo halt` will halt the machine, and on some hardware also power it down.  `sudo halt -p` will power off the system.

Answer (score 0):

The shutdown command can be used to shutdown or reboot the system. You also have a time option.

To shutdown the system now you can use.

```
$ sudo shutdown -h now
```

or

```
$ sudo shutdown -h 0
```

The -h refers to halt of the system.

If you wanted the system to shutdown at a specific time you could use something like this.

```
$ sudo shutdown -h 12:45 "Server is going down for upgrades"
```

A message will be sent out to all users at 12:30 that the system will shutdown at 12:45.

As some of the other answers have mentioned you can also use on most systems.

```
$ sudo halt
$ sudo poweroff
```

To reboot the system you can use the same commands I have mentioned just substitute the halt for reboot or the -h for an -r for example.

```
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```