# Which command is issued when I choose "Shutdown..."?

Tags: unity, shutdown

I have noticed that some of my machines do not switch off (since the upgrade to Precise) when I choose "Shutdown..." from the menu in the upper right corner of Unity. If the system is powered down or not is a kind of random. However, whenever I use the Terminal to `sudo shutdown -h now` it will switch off the machine reliably. After having read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/190214/6232), I wonder what command Unity issues to initiate the shutdown (and power off) of the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu's session indicator relies on `dbus` calls, for example the equivalent command in terminal would be this:

```
qdbus com.canonical.Unity /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.Shutdown
```

As for whether or not some of the machines don't shutdown, I would assume either a bug or dbus calls are being blocked by something